# VSCode Extension Ask For A Date In ISO 8601 Format

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am building a VSCode extension that allows users to generate pages (sample landing pages, documentation, etc) among other things (bug tracking, saving code snippets, tools, etc) and one of the properties is a date. How do I take user input and make sure it is a date, and if not convert to date format? window.showInputBox() is how I usually get info, but I need a date picker, if possible.